# How to motivate the $(at^2,2at)$ parameterization of the parabola?

Tags: conic-sections, parametrization

In most books I find on conic sections, almost all of the parabolas are found after parameterizing the parabola $y^2=4ax$ as: $y=2at$,$x=at^2$. in problem book I am using, it goes so far to say this is the **best** parameterization. Of course, best is subjective, but this certainly seems a very 'esteemed' parameterization.

My question: How would one motivate this parameterization? / What is the reason this parameterization gives so many nice properties? Eg:

If the two parameter value correspond to end of focal chord, then: $$t_1t_2=-1$$

The slope of the normal at parameter $t$ is given as $$-t$$ etc

Comment: We tend to avoid square roots ( can be one of the reason), a similar parameterization is $(\frac{t^2}{4a},t)$

Comment: This parametrization avoids fractions, avoids square roots and so is easier to work with when solving problems. In any case the parametrization should represent the whole curve. If we take $x = t$, we will have $y = \pm \sqrt{...}$ which leads to two different parametrization for curve above x-axis and below it.